# How do I run these two queries at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL to run a query and I'm trying to figure out a way to turn it into one larger query or if I can combine the two.

```
var query1 = "
    SELECT * FROM employee 
    LEFT JOIN role ON employee.role_id = role.id 
    LEFT JOIN department ON role.department_id = department.id";
var query2 = "
    SELECT CONCAT(m.first_name,' ', m.last_name) AS manager_name 
    FROM employee e 
    JOIN employee m on e.manager_id = m.employee_id";
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join.

```
SELECT e.*, r.*, d.*, IFNULL(CONCAT(m.first_name,' ', m.last_name), 'No manager') AS manager_name
FROM employee AS e
LEFT JOIN employee AS m ON e.manager_id = m.employee_id
LEFT JOIN role AS r ON e.role_id = r.id 
LEFT JOIN department AS d ON r.department_id = d.id";
```

Comment: This is great, however I am no longer seeing manager themselves as they do not have a manager. I think it somehow filtered out those who do not report to someone.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Didn't you have the same problem with `$query2`?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little new to mySQL. So I could get the employee info for those who don't have a manager by using LEFT JOIN employee again?

Comment: Ahhh I see. I didn't know how to set the default. Thank you!